# Unsure how to correct these errors python chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot

I have been trying to write a quick little chatbot based on some home searching and learning.
I keep getting these errors when the chatbot is going to print its response to me.

```
2021-05-14 13:34:40.197411: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/TomDootson/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/Chatbot.py", line 57, in <module>
    ints = predict_class(message)
  File "C:/Users/TomDootson/PycharmProjects/Chatbot/Chatbot.py", line 41, in predict_class
    return_list.append({'intent': classes[r[0]], 'probability': str(r[1])})
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the python script I have written. Any pointing in the right direction would be great.

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = pickle.load(open('words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = pickle.load(open('classes.pkl', 'rb'))
model = load_model('chatbot_model.h5')

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words

def bag_of_words(sentence):
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    bag = [0] * len(words)
    for w in sentence_words:
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word == w:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag)

def predict_class(sentence):
    bow = bag_of_words(sentence)
    res = model.predict(np.array([bow]))[0]
    ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
    results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]

    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append({'intent': classes[r[0]], 'probability': str(r[1])})
    return return_list

def get_response(intents_list, intents_json):
    tag = intents_list[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if i['tag'] == tag:
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return result

print('Hello, I am online. Go ahead')

while True:
    message = input('')
    ints = predict_class(message)
    res = get_response(ints, intents)
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error probably comes from the `classes[r[0]]` part, in particular r[0] will be the index of the prediction (from 0 to the length of the input array) an you are using it to index the classes list (that is probably way shorter than the list of prediction).